# Copying a background for different variations in Flash

Tags: layers, adobe-flash, adobe-animate

I am used to Gimp and have the ability to make custom brushes and this way greatly reduce the time of animating one animation, but I would like to use Flash and get more serious.

I would like to achieve in Flash what I do in Gimp by simply creating a background layer (face without the mouth), copying it 300 times and than applying different mouth brushes on each one. This way I don't have to draw a single thing more than once. Can something like that be done in Flash?

If so, which would be a better / possible option within Flash speed wise - if any:

1) Creating the face frame without the mouth and copying it on 1 layer hundreds of times (F6 ?) and than dropping the different mouth symbols on each frame from the library? ...OR...

2) Having the face on 1 layer and dropping the different mouth symbols on frames that are on a second layer? --- (Would that be even possible to export without having the background frame also copied hundreds of times?)

Answer (score 0):

Best is not defined. You would actualy probably do neither as such.

For the body you'd use 2 (output and input is decoupled so output does not need separate layers for it to export it as a frame). But for the mouth you would most likely just use one symbol that has a animation underneath it for all the mouth shapes you use. And then you control from the main animation, so that you get to chose for each frame which mouth frame to use. But yes you could drop symbols but it would be painful to change things later.

Comment: PS: flash does not exist as such anymore its called adobe animate